# EE "Assets" not recognizing FLV file

Tags: ee2, assets, pixelandtonic

I've installed P&T "Assets", set up an upload directory "/videos", added 4 files to it, and had Assets "index" that folder: http://d.pr/i/kG39

Assets ignores the .flv file but finds, or I presume "indexes" the other 3: http://d.pr/i/UCSw

I'm able to add meta data as expected.

How can I make Assets recognize the .flv file? What about other kinds of files?

Cheers,

-Brandon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look in system/expressionengine/config/mimes.php, is 'flv' in that list? If not, try adding:

```
'flv'  =>  'video/x-flv',
```

Comment: This has gotten me many times over the years - no idea why they don't include it as a standard datatype.